# Are These Consonants & 7-Letters Spelling Rule?

Tags: согласные

Consonants:

- ж, ш, ц, ч, щ (Hissing Sounds)
- л, р, б, в, г, д, м, н, з (Resonant Sounds)
- х, п, к, т, ф, с (Voiceless)

7-Letters Spelling Rule:

- г, к, х, ж, ш, щ, ч

Just to confirm the letters so that I can fully understand how to construct the 6 cases.